# Subgraph isomorphism reduction from the Clique problem

Tags: graphs, np-complete, reductions, graph-isomorphism

I was trying to understand the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgraph_isomorphism_problem) proof for NP-completeness of subgraph isomorphism by reduction from the clique problem. It's really just one sentence:

> Let $H$ be the complete graph $K_k$; then, the answer to the subgraph isomorphism problem for $G$ and $H$ is equal to the answer to the clique problem for $G$ and $k$.

In the subgraph isomorphism problem, $G$ and $H$ are not constrained in any way (e.g., $H$ is not constrained to complete graphs). Yet, in the proof, Wikipedia just states "let $H$ be the complete graph $K_k$". It's not defined what $K_k$ represents or why $H$ suddenly becomes constrained to a complete graph.

Comment: From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_graph): $K_k$ denotes the complete graph on $k$ vertices. Some [sources](https://books.google.es/books?id=ZWTDQ6H6gsUC&pg=PA436&redir_esc=y&hl=es#v=onepage&q&f=false) claim that the letter $K$ stands for the German word _komplett_, while other [sources](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_graph#cite_note-4) state that $K$ honors the contributions of _Kazimierz Kuratowski_ to graph theory.

Answer (score 4):

The decision version of the clique problem asks whether a given graph $G$ contains a complete graph with $k$ vertices as subgraph. The wikipedia article just explains why the decision version of the clique problem is a special case of the subgraph isomorphism problem. Namely if the graph $H$ is the complete graph with $k$ vertices, then the answer to this special subgraph isomorphism problem is just the answer to the decision version of the clique problem.

This shows that subgraph isomorphism is NP-hard, since the clique problem is NP-complete. But the subgraph isomorphism is obviously in NP, since it a given monomorphism from $H$ to $G$ can efficiently be checked to be a monomorphism. So we can conclude that subgraph isomorphism is NP-complete.

Comment: Is H constrained to be a complete graph in the subgraph isomorphism problem? If it is not constrained, how is the proof still valid?

Comment: @AtteJuvonen In the subgraph isomorphism problem, H can be any graph, which includes the case that H is a complete graph. The goal is to use the subgraph isomorphism problem to solve the clique problem (not the other way round, like you seem to assume).

Answer (score 0):

You misunderstood the proof of NP-completeness of Subgraph Isomorphism (SI).

1. We know that SI $\in$ NP because we can check its solution in polynomial time.
2. **Any** instance of clique problem (which is NP-complete) can be reduced in polynomial time to **some** instance of SI. This concludes that **any** problem in NP can be reduced to **some** instance of SI.

If you read the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-completeness#Formal_definition) of NP-completeness, you will find out that its requirement satisfied by word **any**. The word **some** doesn't contradict it in any way.