# Generalization of Subgraph Isomorphism

Tags: np-complete, clique

I am wondering how to prove that Subgraph Isomorphism is NP Complete.  Wikipedia indicates that the CLIQUE problem can be used to demonstrate this, but I can't figure out how. I also found this link that demonstrates how Subgraph Isomorphism reduces to CLIQUE, but I can't figure out how to reverse it.  [Subgraph isomorphism reduction from the Clique problem](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/64509/subgraph-isomorphism-reduction-from-the-clique-problem)

Here is a formal example of the problem from [DASGUPTA 8.10](http://algorithmics.lsi.upc.edu/docs/Dasgupta-Papadimitriou-Vazirani.pdf): 
Given as input two undirected graphs G and H, determine whether G is a subgraph of H (that is, whether by deleting certain vertices and edges of H we obtain a graph that is, up to renaming of vertices, identical to G), and if so, return the corresponding mapping of V (G) into V (H).

Comment: Well, what happens if you choose $G$ to be a clique with $k$ vertices?

Comment: Can you do that?  If so, that is the answer because a clique will contain every possible subgraph of size k.  But is it legal to constrain the input to a specific G that is fully connected?  I thought it had to take any graphs G and H

Comment: The question you link actually shows that clique reduces to subgraph isomorphism, which is the exact thing you're looking for.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Subgraph isomorphism reduction from the Clique problem](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/64509/subgraph-isomorphism-reduction-from-the-clique-problem)

Comment: The link I provided assumes a fully connected graph but my question only specifies any graph H.  Is the reduction still possible/valid in this case?

Comment: The link explains how to reduce $k$-clique to subgraph isomorphism, which is exactly the exercise you're trying to complete. I think the problem is that you haven't fully understood reductions and you probably need face-to-face help to get over that. It's the sort of thing that can probably be explained in a five-minute interactive chat but which takes forever in these little comments.

Comment: Thanks @DavidRicherby.  I haven't heard of such a resource.  Do you have a recommendation for where I can get a face-to-face explanation?

Comment: I found this definition thanks to your comment: Problem A is a generalization of Problem B if every instance of B is also an instance of A.  This implies B can be reduced to A.  In this case, every instance of a CLIQUE of size k s going to have an ISOMORPHIC SUBGRAPH of G in H because of the definition of a CLIQUE. so ISOMORPHIC SUBGRAPH can be reduced to CLIQUE.

Answer (score 1):

A subgraph is isomorphic to a clique if, and only if, it *is* a clique.

Comment: But what if H doesn't have a clique the same size as G?  There are lots of permutations of H that may or may not be isomorphic with G.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. If H is isomorphic to G, any permutation of H is also isomorphic.

Comment: I thought H could be any graph, not just a graph that is isomorphic to G.

Comment: We're trying to reduce $k$-clique to sub graph isomorphism. That means we're given a graph $F$ and a number $k$, and we need to produce graphs $G$ and $H$ such that $G$ has a subgraph isomorphic to $H$ if, and only if, $F$ has a clique of size at least $k$. We get to choose the input to subgraph isomorphism.

Comment: Thanks for addressing my concern.  So in my other reduction exercises, I have taken the input to a known NP Complete problem, modified it, and produced the same answer as the known NPC but with a unproven NP Complete problem.  For example, I took the input for SAT (known NPC) and modified it to be a valid input for 3SAT.  Then I modified the output of 3SAT to give the same result as would have been obtained by SAT.  So, that is what I know how to do.  This seems to be a different problem.  A cascade of sorts.  Am I correct in my understanding?